# getThumbnail method returning blurry thumbnails?

Tags: android, image, gridview, thumbnails

I want to show **Thumbnails** for images present on device in a **GridView** and I'm using [getThumbnail](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html#getThumbnail%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20long,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) method to get thumbnails. But for some reason when I set returned thumbnails to ImageViews in gridview, they are not clear(blurry). For example, if there's a text in an image then I'm not able to read that text in my app whereas I can read it in the native android gallery app. I hope this gives a idea of what my problem is. I think its probably because the imageview size is greater than image size.

I have tried to use methods like [extractThumbnail](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#extractThumbnail%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) in conjunction with **BitmapFactory.Options inSampleSize** but sometimes it generate **OutOfMemoryException**.

What should I do to resolve this issue so that the thumbnails are as clear as they appear in android native gallery application?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, getThumbnail will return a scaled image. If you are then scaling that image back up to fit in your GridView, then that would account for the blurriness.

You can try scaling the images to the correct size yourself, then displaying it to the GridView.

You may also want to look at [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). It is an awesome Open Source project that helps with Image Loading and can fix your memory issue.

Comment: @BeagleBreath-Thank you for the response. Yeah, getThumbnail does return the scaled bitmap and it depends upon kind of thumbnail you are requesting(MINI_KIND, MICRO_KIND) and currently I'm requesting MINI_KIND which is 512 x 384 as mentioned on developers site. And could you please elaborate on your second statement on how can I try scaling the images to correct size? Also, I have tried using UIL and Picasso but I'm getting the same result.